# How to monitor progress of a long running command?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, makefile

I have a long running script that outputs a lot of log lines as it runs. My specific task is to count lines in 50K files for a total of 2TB of data. However, but the question also applies to running a long make, or an install script.

How can I show the progress of the long running script on a single line (i.e. reusing the same line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited]

If the number of lines is enough, and you don't need actual percentage, this simple awk one-liner does the trick:

```
awk '{printf "\r%s", NR}'
```

When running `make` it would be:

```
make | awk '{printf "\r%s", NR}'
```

Note the `\r` at the beginning of the printf format - it rewinds the caret back to the start of the line, reusing the line.

Comment: What's the purpose of `parallel` in that pipeline? It doesn't seem like counting lines from `stdin` is parallelizable. Anyway, you can use awk directly to count lines:  `ls | awk 'NR%50000==0{printf "\r%8d", NR}'`

Comment: It isn't counting lines form stdin, it counts lines in the files it accepts via stdin, which AFAIK can be parallelized.

Your awk foo is better than mine though, I didn't know about `NR`.

Comment: Ah, good point. But then you're throwing away the counts, since you only track the number of lines output by `wc`, and not the line counts written into those lines. Perhaps you meant `s+=$1`, in which case my `awk` is not the same.

Comment: By the way, if you want something prettier, take a look at `dialog`.

Comment: @rici: You're right, I did use $1 in my original script and changed it here. I changed the answer to show progress on `make`, and used your syntax, which is much easier to remember.